# How to include apostrophe ('), in the following regex expression in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Following is regex expression for an address field which can contain (.), apostrophe ('), dash (-), number, (#), (@), ampersand (&), slash (/), and spaces.

But I am unable to add regex for an apostrophe (').

```
address: ['', [Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9- &@/#.]+$')]],
```

Comment: Just escape it: `\'`

Comment: and also escape `\/` backslash.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `html`, `angular` or `typescript`. That's just a basic `javascript` topic: how do strings work

Answer (score 1):

Since you are putting your regex pattern inside a single-quote delimited string, you must escape the single quote with a forward slash `\'`:

```
Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9- &@/#.\']+$') // note the forward slash and a single quote
```

Or just change your string to a double-quote delimited string.

```
Validators.pattern("^[A-Za-z0-9- &@/#.']+$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the string passed to pattern() with a double quotes("") or backticks(``) and add an apostrophe(') inside the sqaure brackets[] in the regular expression,

```
address: ['', [Validators.pattern("^[A-Za-z0-9- &@/#.']+$")]]
```